# Integrate Azure Multi-Factor-Authentication in website to authenticate its users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have a website (built in PHP), OS of web-server is Linux (Ubuntu) from AWS EC2,

I want to integrate Azure MFA in website to authenticate users using 2FA (2 factor authentication),

I checked this code using Node JS https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect

It is a Sample app from Azure, in which a user can logged in sample app using Azure credentials, and can fetch profile information from Azure,

It worked fine for me, but:

1) It will need to add an user in Active Directory (AD) first, so can I authenticate users directly, without registering on Azure AD?
Also, I have more than 3000 active users in website, will I need to register them all?

2) User completely redirected on Microsoft site during authentication process,  Is there any way without redirecting, or by using some UI stuff (using popup window)?

Any help or suggestions will helpful for me,

Thanks in advance,
Herry

Comment: Have a look on this answer and let me know if you have any more query. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for answering, Have a question regarding user, suppose I have an user in my website with email `a@a.com`, can I register an user with same email id in AD? so that I can link things, and in which field I should store email?

Comment: In Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C, you can use different types of accounts. Azure Active Directory, Azure Active Directory B2B, and Azure Active Directory B2C share in the types of user accounts that can be used you could here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview || You could also have a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-guest-to-role || Just make sure which one meet your requirements. Let me know if you have any more query. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I will check about Azure B2C,

Comment: Thanks a lot, You can ask if you have any more query. happy coding !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. It will need to add an user in Active Directory (AD) first?**

Yeah Right you are! First you need to add your user on Azure portal then they need to authenticate while they would try to access anything in each operation.

**2. Can I authenticate users directly, without registering on Azure AD?**

No you cannot! For authentication you need to define a user on your azure portal first.

**3. I have more than 3000 active users in website, will I need to
    register them all?**

As you have thousand of user on your web side you can add them in a bulk operation.
To avoid manual registration you could ad it using [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) command. If you add all of your user on a [CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) file you can add them up easily by following script:

having all of your user CSV file you could run this `New-AzureADUser` command like below format.

> ```
> foreach($user in import-csv "E:\userinfo.csv") 
> { 
>      Write-Host "Processing item with.. UserName="$user.DisplayName
>
>    # Make use of variables like $user.DisplayName and so on in your commands here..
>    # New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $user.DisplayName ... and so on..
> }
> ```

You may have a look on referred documents for similar way in a great details [here](https://charbelnemnom.com/2018/03/how-to-create-bulk-users-in-azure-active-directory-with-powershell-azuread-powershell-aad/)

**3. User completely redirected on Microsoft site during authentication
    process, Is there any way without redirecting, or by using some UI
    stuff (using popup window)?**

As you are using [OpenIdConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code) protocol for authentication in this flow you cannot stop redirection on Microsoft site during authentication process. But there is a way 
using [Resource owner password credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

> It is not recommend to use the ***Resource owner password credentials
>   flow ROPC*** in this scenario. It is more like phishing site if the users
>   doesn't trust your web app.
>
> The ***resource owner password credentials*** (i.e., username and
>   password) can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an
>   access token. The credentials should only be used when there is a high
>   degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the
>   client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged
>   application), and when other authorization grant types are not
>   available (such as an authorization code)

The redirection to the identity provider is expected when we choose a interactive flow of **OAuth 2 Authorization Framework** because this is how it works!

Hope it will help you to figure out your work around. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any SDK available to implement ROPC?

Comment: @HerryShawn I guess It doesn't require any SDK. Its implementation is pretty simple and easy understanding. Here is a git hub sample for you https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2 || Before implement ROPC I would suggest you to read this official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc || Specially the important Note. Still if you need code sample just let me know I would update my answer. Thank You.

Comment: Hy, @Md Farid, I checked B2C, It seems that B2C is the thing, which suits my requirement, But can I implement only Sign In process through B2C?

Comment: That's mean you want to customize your b2c sign in page?

Comment: Yes, I want to customize the sign in page to hide/show some of features, Also please let me know if there are some API to add new users in AD?

Comment: @HerryShawn Yes you can. Could you please raise another question what you want to do, Once you make it clear, I would definitely help you there.

Comment: @HerryShawn I have noticed :)