# Azure Active Directory MFA

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Our clients uses Azure AD for their operations and wanted to integrate the Azure AD MFA to our web app (PHP) for additional security. Is this possible without using the Microsoft Identity Platform (SSO)? I also cant seem to find a REST API for the Azure AD MFA. Any alternate options that I could use for implementing MFA? Some recommendations would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @kavyasaraboju-MT. Thanks a lot for this! It is helpful yeah. I'll mark it as the accepted answer. One question though, we already have our own database of users in our web app. Is it possible to maybe connect/sync the two identities together? Could it be done on the Azure AD or does it need to be on our end?  I hope that made sense. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not already registered the php app in azure ad like below:
Quickstart: [app registration-general- Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet#step-1-register-your-application)

Go for app registration in azuread .

1. Set Redirect URI like  https://your.domain.name/oauth.php
2. Copy the client ID and tenant ID, to paste in  _OAUTH_TENANTID and _OAUTH_CLIENTID in config.inc.
3. In Certificates & secrets page copy the secret value by adding a new secret,which cannot be accessed later.So copy when created.
4. Paste this into _OAUTH_SECRET within config.inc. Make sure _OAUTH_METHOD contains 'secret'.

You can see detailed info in here in [Katy's Tech Blog](https://katystech.blog/projects/php-azuread-oauth-login) .

See   [PHP Azure AD login with demo site (using oAuth)-GitHub reference](https://github.com/CoasterKaty/PHPAzureADoAuth) for code configuration details.

For including multifaction authentication**(MFA)** :

- You may Go to azure ad > enterprise apps and check for the app you
  have just registered and create a policy to include MFA Requirement
  which asks users for additional authentication with the methods you
  enables like sms, phone call etc

[image]

**next**

[image]

Or you can directly go for conditional access and select app required while creating access policy.

[image]

After all set up in conditional access, make sure to Enable policy and save ,to start authenticating with azure ad which requires MFA.

Also check  **references:**

1. Azure AD authentication with PHP using Microsoft Graph. [a single PHP page](https://gist.github.com/DragonBe/8af1044185ef14e61cd98e6086e3fc59)
2. [Deployment considerations for Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-getstarted)
3. [Integrate Azure Multi-Factor-Authentication in website to authenticate its users - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497327/integrate-azure-multi-factor-authentication-in-website-to-authenticate-its-users)